# ALSA audio error when playing videos

Tags: arch-linux, audio, alsa

I use Arch Linux on an x86_64 desktop. I recently did a full system update and now I seem to be getting no sound from videos. For example, I get no audio in YouTube videos and I get the following error if I try to play a video in mpv:

```
$ mpv CORE.RPL 
 (+) Video --vid=1 (escape124 320x208 15.000fps)
 (+) Audio --aid=1 (pcm_u8 2ch 44100Hz)
File tags:
 Title: RPLFAKE movie                                                                    
[autoconvert] Converting rgb555 -> rgb565
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:999:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
[ao/alsa] Playback open error: No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
[ao/jack] cannot open server
[ao] Failed to initialize audio driver 'jack'
Could not open/initialize audio device -> no sound.
Audio: no audio
VO: [gpu] 320x208 rgb565
V: 00:00:02 / 00:00:11 (24%)
```

I use ALSA direct (no Pulse audio) and OpenRC rather than systemd. The audio was working fine before the update. I do get sound in some applications (e.g. the sound works fine in a couple of games that I have) - the issue seems to be with videos specifically, as far as I can tell.

Does anyone have any suggestions of what might be causing it?

(Note that I want to use ALSA direct, not Jack)

**Update:** (in response to question in the comments)

Output of `aplay -L`:

```
$ aplay -L
null
    Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture)
default
    Default Audio Device
sysdefault
    Default Audio Device
lavrate
    Rate Converter Plugin Using Libav/FFmpeg Library
samplerate
    Rate Converter Plugin Using Samplerate Library
speexrate
    Rate Converter Plugin Using Speex Resampler
jack
    JACK Audio Connection Kit
oss
    Open Sound System
pulse
    PulseAudio Sound Server
speex
    Plugin using Speex DSP (resample, agc, denoise, echo, dereverb)
upmix
    Plugin for channel upmix (4,6,8)
vdownmix
    Plugin for channel downmix (stereo) with a simple spacialization
usbstream:CARD=U0x46d0x81b
    USB Device 0x46d:0x81b
    USB Stream Output
default:CARD=PCH
    HDA Intel PCH, CX20641 Analog
    Default Audio Device
sysdefault:CARD=PCH
    HDA Intel PCH, CX20641 Analog
    Default Audio Device
front:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, CX20641 Analog
    Front output / input
surround21:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, CX20641 Analog
    2.1 Surround output to Front and Subwoofer speakers
surround40:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, CX20641 Analog
    4.0 Surround output to Front and Rear speakers
surround41:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, CX20641 Analog
    4.1 Surround output to Front, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround50:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, CX20641 Analog
    5.0 Surround output to Front, Center and Rear speakers
surround51:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, CX20641 Analog
    5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround71:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, CX20641 Analog
    7.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Side, Rear and Woofer speakers
usbstream:CARD=PCH
    HDA Intel PCH
    USB Stream Output
hdmi:CARD=NVidia,DEV=0
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 0
    HDMI Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=NVidia,DEV=1
    HDA NVidia, DELL S2240L
    HDMI Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=NVidia,DEV=2
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 2
    HDMI Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=NVidia,DEV=3
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 3
    HDMI Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=NVidia,DEV=4
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 4
    HDMI Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=NVidia,DEV=5
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 5
    HDMI Audio Output
usbstream:CARD=NVidia
    HDA NVidia
    USB Stream Output
```

Output of `aplay -l`:

```
$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: CX20641 Analog [CX20641 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [DELL S2240L]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 11: HDMI 5 [HDMI 5]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

I do not have an `/etc/asound.conf` file (nor a per-user `~/.asoundrc` file). I have never had/needed it in the past and the sound via ALSA has always worked fine.

I am using Iceweasel (Firefox based) for YouTube. `aplay` with a random .wav file also does not work and I get a very similar error message:

```
$ aplay 0x0d.wav
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:999:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
aplay: main:867: audio open error: No such file or directory
```

Comment: And BTW, prior to launching mpv, make absolutely sure that no other app has locked the driver for its exclusive use. Some browsers do that, soundservers do that too.

Comment: No card 0 ??? errr… So please start editing from scratch (since you don't get any) /etc/asound.conf , enter the 3 following lines : defaults.pcm.card 1 / defaults.pcm.device 1 / defaults.ctl.card 1 (omit the slash only written here to mark line separation) then save and reboot.

Comment: @MC68020 so, I think card 0 was assigned to my USB webcam mic (which obviously has no output). I tried your suggestion, but on rebooting, the Intel chip had been set to card 0 and it still didn't work. I think I am understanding better what the issue is though, and I see the Arch Wiki has advice to ensure the devices get set to the right card numbers. I will try that and see if it helps.